# Nested divs and mobile columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working with a row that has text above and 4 icons below each as a listed div. I have them spanning 100% of the div on desktop, 2 on tablet, and I can't get them to stack 2 on mobile. I only get them to stack in 1 on top of one another. Any idea on how to get them to display 2? I used a media query to make the font smaller but I'm somehow stuck.

I tried adding class col-xs-6 to the divs but that didn't seem to work. I'm pretty dang new to bootstrap, so I may of miss understood it's grid systems.

Sorry, I'm a newbie trying to learn and I've looked at other websites source code but couldn't find a solution.

```
Desktop:
[[ MAIN DIV W/ TEXT ]]
[[1]] [[2]] [[3]] [[4]]

Tablet:
[[ MAIN DIV ]]
[[1]] [[2]]
[[3]] [[4]]
Mobile:
[[ MAIN DIV ]]
[[1]]
[[2]]
[[3]]
[[4]]
```

Here is a fiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/hecq0yq6/1/

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

.discuss {
  background-color: #00CCDD;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.discuss h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
}

.discuss p {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.icons {
  margin-top: 20px;
  /* margin-bottom: 40px;*/
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.icons a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .icons,
  h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- DISCUSS SECTION NESTED WITH ICONS -->
<div class="row col-xs-12 discuss">
  <h1 class="text-center">HEADER</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Not sure why you use lorem ipsum?</p>

  <!-- NESTED 4 COLUMNS TEST -->

  <div class="row">

    <!-- Div col-sm-3 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 icons"> <a href="http://www.google.com" class="icons"><i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:48px;"></i><br>
              <h3>Icon<br>
              #1</h3>
              </a> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 icons"> <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="icons"><i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size:48px;"></i><br>
              <h3>Icon<br>
              #2</h3>
              </a> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 icons"> <a href="http://www.dicks.com" class="icons"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" style="font-size:48px;"></i><br>
              <h3>Icon<br>
              #3</h3>
              </a> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 icons"> <a href="http://www.cnn.com" class="icons"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="font-size:48px;"></i><br>
              <h3>Icon<br>
              #4</h3>
              </a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.col-xs-6` in addition to or instead of `.col-md-6`.

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

.discuss {
  background-color: #00CCDD;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.discuss h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
}

.discuss p {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.icons {
  margin-top: 20px;
  /* margin-bottom: 40px;*/
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.icons a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .icons,
  h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- DISCUSS SECTION NESTED WITH ICONS -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 discuss">

    <h1 class="text-center">HEADER</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <p>
      Not sure why you use lorem ipsum?
    </p>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 icons">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="icons">
          <i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
          <br>
          <h3>Icon<br> #1</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 icons">
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="icons">
          <i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
          <br>
          <h3>Icon<br> #2</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 icons">
        <a href="http://www.dicks.com" class="icons">
          <i class="fa fa-briefcase" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
          <br>
          <h3>Icon<br> #3</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 icons">
        <a href="http://www.cnn.com" class="icons">
          <i class="fa fa-file-text" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
          <br>
          <h3>Icon<br> #4</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

FWIW `.row` should be used on separate element than one with a column class like `.col-xs-12`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I saw other people using .row with .col-xs-* I guess I should not follow other's blindly.

Comment: You could potentially use them together if it got you the layout you needed but is definitely atypical. `.row` has a negative left/right margin that offsets the padding of the columns that butt up against the left and right side of `.row` so the gutter on the outside edge doesn't get doubled up.